# C++ : DirectX Texture is Misaligned/Shifted

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to render a square with a texture. Does anyone know why this texture appears to be shifted or misaligned?

Here is how it's supposed to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv6fS.jpg

[image: imgur]

Here is how the issue looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXMM7.jpg

[image: imgur]

```
auto createVSTask = loadVSTask.then([this](const std::vector<byte>& fileData) {
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateVertexShader(
            &fileData[0],
            fileData.size(),
            nullptr,
            &m_vertexShader
        )
    );

    static const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "NORMAL",   0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateInputLayout(
            vertexDesc,
            ARRAYSIZE(vertexDesc),
            &fileData[0],
            fileData.size(),
            &m_inputLayout
        )
    );
});

auto createPSTask = loadPSTask.then([this](const std::vector<byte>& fileData) {
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreatePixelShader(
            &fileData[0],
            fileData.size(),
            nullptr,
            &m_pixelShader
        )
    );

    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC constantBufferDesc(sizeof(ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer), D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER);
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateBuffer(
            &constantBufferDesc,
            nullptr,
            &m_constantBuffer
        )
    );
});

auto createPrimitiveTask = (createPSTask && createVSTask).then([this]() {

    const VertexPositionColor cubeVertices[] =
    {
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),  DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f) },
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f) },
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f) },
        { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
    };

    static const unsigned short cubeIndices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3
    };

    m_indexCount = ARRAYSIZE(cubeIndices);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData = { 0 };
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = cubeVertices;
    vertexBufferData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vertexBufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc(sizeof(cubeVertices), D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER);
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateBuffer(
            &vertexBufferDesc,
            &vertexBufferData,
            &m_vertexBuffer
        )
    );

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA indexBufferData = { 0 };
    indexBufferData.pSysMem = cubeIndices;
    indexBufferData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    indexBufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBufferDesc(sizeof(cubeIndices), D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER);
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateBuffer(
            &indexBufferDesc,
            &indexBufferData,
            &m_indexBuffer
        )
    );
});

auto loadTDTask = DX::ReadDataAsync(m_textureFile);

auto createSubresourceTask = loadTDTask.then([=](std::vector<byte>& textureData) {

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA textureSubresourceData = { 0 };
    textureSubresourceData.pSysMem = &textureData[0];
    textureSubresourceData.SysMemPitch = 1024;
    textureSubresourceData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = { 0 };
    textureDesc.Width = 256;
    textureDesc.Height = 256;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 0;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(
        &textureDesc,
        nullptr,
        &m_texture
    );

    if (m_texture != NULL)
    {
        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC textureViewDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&textureViewDesc, sizeof(textureViewDesc));
        textureViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
        textureViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        textureViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = -1;
        textureViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            m_d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(
            m_texture.Get(),
            &textureViewDesc,
            &m_textureView
            )
        );

        context->UpdateSubresource(m_texture.Get(), 0, nullptr, &textureData[0], textureSubresourceData.SysMemPitch, textureDesc.Width);
        context->GenerateMips(m_textureView.Get());
    }
}

D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
ZeroMemory(&samplerDesc, sizeof(samplerDesc));
samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 0;
samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 0.0f;

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(
    &samplerDesc,
    &m_sampler
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you please show us the vertex/index buffers? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I updated the source code in the post.

Comment: You can try to use clamp texture addressing to figure if it is a uv problem, or a texture update problem. Also, the last parameter in `UpdateSubresource` should be 0, not width, as it is a depth pitch, and you have none here.

Comment: If I specify D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP, then there is no change in the rendered image by default.  

If I increase the UV coordinates to 1.5 in length/width and specify D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_BORDER, then it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Lseksyq.jpg).  

If I increase the UV coordinates to 1.5 in length/width and specify D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP, then it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/jwtl7cp.jpg).

Comment: @436c75656c657373Programmer What it means is that your texture upload is wrong. Because the texture looks mostly correct, the pitch is right, but you may have forgot to remove the file header from textureData ? In any cases, using constant in your code, like 256 or 1024 assuming the incoming data is compatible is a bad practice, you should forward values to prevent any missmatch.

Comment: You may also want to check your vertex buffer content. The type you use is `VertexPositionColor`, whose name suggests different content. Make sure that it contains the correct data.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  My current assumption is that I created the texture incorrectly.  I used the DirectX Texture Tool to open a jpeg, saved it as a .DDS file, and then tried to load it in textureData.

Comment: @Nico Schertler VertexPositionColor was a struct that I changed from storing an XMFloat3 Color to an XMFloat2 Texture.  As far as I can tell, the vertex buffer content looks okay.

Comment: Then @galop1n is probably right. Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943991(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what is actually in the DDS file. If the black line at the top of the quad is not part of the texture, then this is probably the header.

Comment: Or just use the [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you confirmed that it was no state or geometry problem with the clamp experiment, second, you said you are using a DDS image, and this is the key.

According to your code, the image is 256 width RGBA8, as the stone are 1/8 of that, it means they cover 32*4 = 128 bytes. Close enough, the [DDS header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982(v=vs.85).aspx) is 124 bytes when you do not have the dx10 chunk in it and it explains why the image is offset-ed like that.

All you have to do is skip the header and pass only the image data to `UpdateSubResource`. I invit you to look at the [DDS reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943992(v=vs.85).aspx) to learn how the file is layout so you can read the sizes, format, properly skip to the beginning of the data, and also take advantage of the DDS to store compressed format, and include the mip maps upfront to not use `GenerateMips` that is bad practice.

Comment: To skip the DDS header, should I just skip the first 128 bytes when reading in the binary data in the DDS file?

Comment: I know it's not efficient but my goal is to create a test app that can automatically generate mipmaps, so GenerateMips is needed.

Comment: The DDS header has a know size, and may also contains the optional dx10 extra chunk, to know how much to skip, you need to read the header and test the format tag inside. There is no magic constant here that works all the time.

Comment: Also, even if your goal is to generate mipmap at runtime, GenerateMips remains a bad idea, first, you have no control over the process, what if you want some sharpening or renornalisation for a normal map, second, you cannot use compressed format, and last, you have to use the rendertarget binding that later make texture read less efficient, if you want to generate mips yourself, you need to use temporary buffers that are RT or UAV, write a compute or pixel shader to generate them, then use CopyResource to initialize a proper texture with read only binding.